# How to take Picture Programmatically in iphone App using device camera?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In iPhone App,
Can we take **pictures** at some perticular time intervals **programmatically** by using **iphone  device camera** ?

If yes then please let me know how we can take pictures programmatically in iPhone App?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: same question here. I've been always interested in some photography apps that are capable of doing this..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UIImagePickerController has a [takePicture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) method that can be called programmatically.

Comment: by calling takePicture mathod can i take new still images by using iphone device camera or i can only access the picture library and fatch picture from that

Comment: @Prerak, takePicture is intended to be used to "take new still images by using the device camera." If you're only getting the picture library, make sure you set the sourceType property of your UIImagePickerController to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. That will give you the camera interface.

Comment: @Prerak: I think you can do it, I'm using a free app named TimerCamera in my iPhone and it can take pictures continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIImagePickerController has a takePicture method to take picture.

For more control over the picture you can use AVFoundation header which contains avcapturestillimageoutput method to capture images.  [More Info](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30)

Answer (score 0):

import this file in .h :

```
AVFoundation/AVCaptureInput.h
AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h
AVFoundation/AVCaptureOutput.h
AVFoundation/AVMediaFormat.h
```

put in .m :

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera
{
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CGImageRef cgImage = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    self.theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage ];
    CGImageRelease( cgImage );

    NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    df.calendar = sysCalendar;
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd_MM_yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
    StrCapture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSLog(@"StrCapture : %@",StrCapture);

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.theImage,1);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:StrCapture];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    NSLog(@"ImagePAth : %@",fullPath);
}

- (CGImageRef) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    uint8_t baseAddress = (uint8_t )CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    return newImage;
}
```