# capture image from camera automatically after sometime via coding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, timer, camera

I want to know that is it possible to capture image from the camera automatically after some time delay i.e setting some user defined timer. So when the timer goes to Zero than the iphone/ipad's camera should capture image.

I know how to open camera and capture image when user click on capture button and save it to photo library but dont have any idea about setting timer.

Is it possible ?
Please help me with some links or any reference if it is possible to do.

Comment: you create method and and call that method with the use of timer and add code of capture image in method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController has a takePicture method that can be called programmatically.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4477542/2695503

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is  possible for  to capture image from the camera automatically after some time delay.

Follow this steps to do this :

1.Setting some user defined timer

1. There is a method in UIImagePickerController for taking picture automatically "takePicture"

   So when the timer goes to Zero than call this method.

Thats it.Your problem will be solved.